# Clearing an input type='number' field

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, viewmodel

I am using AngularJS in the ASP.NET MVC application. I have input type='number' with this markup

```html
 <input type="number" name="number1" id="number1" class="form-control" placeholder="@String.Format(Labels.numberX, "1")"
                       min="-2147483648" max="2147483647"
                       ng-model="currentGuest.number1" />
```

The number1 is defined as int in the ViewModel. The problem happens when the user clears the number from the field. It becomes NULL and I am getting bad request when I am trying to post data back. I see a following solution here - define these numbers as int? in the ViewModel and use AutoMapper to convert NULL to 0 when converting back to the model.

Any other ideas with less code to implement?

Comment: can you add please code from your MVC controller to question ?

Comment: shouldn't you be using `angular-ui mask ` instead of placeholder

Comment: @sylwester It doesn't reach the controller code, the error is handled by the directive on the bad request. Right now I've changed all the numbers to be nullable in the ViewModel and testing.

Comment: MethodMan - I am not sure - do you think it's relevant?

Answer (score 0):

Adding our own attribute NullableNumber(DefaultValue=0)] and making all numbers nullable in the ViewModel solved the problem.